# Documentation of environment variables of Hyperledger Fabric components

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Recently I was going through some implementations of hyperledger fabric , and I came across with some confusing environment variables for fabric components(some of which listed below). Is there any documentation where I can read about all the environment variables of fabric components. Currently I am am confused about below environment variables of fabric peer:

1. CORE_PEER_ADDRESS CORE_PEER_NETWORKID
2. CORE_PEER_ENDORSER_ENABLED
3. CORE_PEER_ID
4. CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED
5. CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE
6. CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All environment variables actually mirrored configuration parameters prefixed with `CORE_PEER`, most of them have descent documentation inside `core.yaml`. The intent behind setting these parameters in environmental variable is to been able to override them inside the docker containers.

So for example `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS`,  `CORE_PEER_NETWORKID`, `CORE_PEER_ID`:

```
###############################################################################
#
#    Peer section
#
###############################################################################
peer:

    # The Peer id is used for identifying this Peer instance.
    id: jdoe

    # The networkId allows for logical seperation of networks
    networkId: dev   

    # The endpoint this peer uses to listen for inbound chaincode connections.
    # If this is commented-out, the listen address is selected to be
    # the peer's address (see below) with port 7052
    # chaincodeListenAddress: 0.0.0.0:7052

    # The endpoint the chaincode for this peer uses to connect to the peer.
    # If this is not specified, the chaincodeListenAddress address is selected.
    # And if chaincodeListenAddress is not specified, address is selected from
    # peer listenAddress.
    # chaincodeAddress: 0.0.0.0:7052

    # When used as peer config, this represents the endpoint to other peers
    # in the same organization. For peers in other organization, see
    # gossip.externalEndpoint for more info.
    # When used as CLI config, this means the peer's endpoint to interact with
    address: 0.0.0.0:7051
```

and you can find more [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release/sampleconfig/core.yaml).

Comment: It was great help. Thanks !